# Changing Sort Direction On GroupField With Java Through The Crystal Reports API

Tags: java, crystal-reports

With Crystal Reports I am able to modify the field that is being grouped on for a given report but cannot seem to figure out how to change the direction that the field is being sorted on. Basically I am trying something like this:

```
Sorts sorts=reportdocument.getDataDefinition.getSorts
ISort s=sorts.get(index)
    if(s.getSortField.getName equals field.getName)
        s.setDirection(...)
```

I have also tried removing the Sort instance at the given index and created a new one to replace it and that didnt work either. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can do this, or know of any good resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how to do this and am posting what I did in case it will help anyone else. Basically you need to do something like the following:

```
GroupController gc=...
IGroup old=gc.findGroup(some field)
IGroup newGroup=(IGroup)old.clone(true);

ISort sort=new Sort();
sort.setSortField(field sorting on);
sort.setDirection(SortDirection);

newGroup.setSort(sort);
gc.modify(old,newGroup);
```

[This link](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/cr4E/en/cr4e_relnotes_en.pdf) (not only was virtually all I could find on this) but was also semi helpful.